# Dynamically changed dropdowns are not refreshing. (Fogbugz)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fogbugz

I posted this on the fogbugz boards but I was hoping for a quicker response.

The script below does what I want it to do except you need to change the ixproject field (Probably because my other projects do not uses subcategory) for the dropdowns to be updated with the new values. Is there a way to refresh certain html elements after their values have been changed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var categoryChanged = $('#ixCategory');
  var reloadProject = $('#ixProject');
  //  We don't need Schedule Item so remove it.  From our options.
  var removeScheduleItem = document.getElementById("ixCategory");
  var select = document.getElementById("subcategorya85");

  //Remove all options that may exist.  
  function resetSelectBox(){
      var select = document.getElementById("subcategorya85");
      select.options.length = 0;
  }

    //Remove all options before starting.  
    $(document).ready(function() {
      resetSelectBox();
      select.options[0] = new Option("--");
      //removes schedule item from ixcategory
      removeScheduleItem.remove(3);
    });
    categoryChanged.on("change", function(event){
    if (($('#ixCategory')[0].selectedIndex == 0))
    {   
      resetSelectBox();
      select.options[0] = new Option("A", "A");
      select.options[1] = new Option("B", "B");
      select.options[2] = new Option("C", "C");
    } 
    else
    if (($('#ixCategory')[0].selectedIndex == 1)) 
    {
      resetSelectBox();
      select.options[0] = new Option("D", "D");
      select.options[1] = new Option("E", "E");
    }else
    if (($('#ixCategory')[0].selectedIndex == 2)) 
    {
      resetSelectBox();
      select.options[0] = new Option("F", "F");
    }else
    if (($('#ixCategory')[0].selectedIndex == 3)) 
    {
        resetSelectBox();
        select.options[0] = new Option("G", "G");
    }
  }) 
});
```

EDIT: I copied the exact same script to a Fiddle and got the desired result. http://jsfiddle.net/themaniac27/VNfFH/

What do I need to do differently to get this to work in Fogbugz. This was attempted using the fogbugz on demand trial.

Comment: What issue are you having? It isn't very clear

Comment: Why do you have a $(document).ready inside a $(document).ready ?

Comment: @Sam When I run the script in Fogbugz, the select element does not update.  The old option values are still selectable until the user category is changed by the user.

Comment: @jperelli Because I'm new at Jquery and do not know any better.  I'll fix it later but after testing it, it isn't the cause of my problem.  This is just bad programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like [the fogbugz boards gave me an answer](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/10683/dynamically-changed-dropdowns-are-not-refreshing/10695#10695).

> FogBugz' droplists have a variety of additional functionality added to
>   them, so they can be a little tricky to modify directly. Basically,
>   you need to call DropListControl.refresh() and pass in the underlying
>    DOM element. Another thing to consider is that FogBugz can
>   ajaxily transition from viewing a case to editing a case.